# Planning error with path constrains

Tags: ros, motion-planning, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Moveit (0.6.15-Alpha) in ROS Indigo to control an arm.
The planning goes well untill I try to plan a new position which has some path constrains (orientation and position on two axis of the end effector).

The code looks like this:

```
    // Orientation constrain adding
    moveit_msgs::Constraints flip_constrains;
    moveit_msgs::OrientationConstraint flip_orientation;
    flip_orientation.link_name = eef;
    flip_orientation.header.frame_id = base_reference;
    flip_orientation.orientation = move_group_->getCurrentPose().pose.orientation;              
    flip_orientation.absolute_x_axis_tolerance = 0.15;
    flip_orientation.absolute_y_axis_tolerance = 0.15;
    flip_orientation.absolute_z_axis_tolerance = 0.15;
    flip_orientation.weight = 0.7;
    flip_constrains.orientation_constraints.push_back(flip_orientation);
    // Position constrain adding
    moveit_msgs::PositionConstraint flip_position;
    flip_position.link_name = eef;
    flip_position.header.frame_id = base_reference;
    flip_position.target_point_offset.x = 0; //target.position.x;
    flip_position.target_point_offset.y = target.position.y;
    flip_position.target_point_offset.z = target.position.z;
    flip_position.weight = 1.0;
    flip_constrains.position_constraints.push_back(flip_position);
    move_group_->setPathConstraints(flip_constrains);
    target.position.x = req.distance;
    target.orientation = move_group_->getCurrentPose().pose.orientation;

    move_group_->setPoseTarget(target);
move_group_->setStartState(*move_group_->getCurrentState());

bool success = move_group_->plan(move_plan);
ROS_INFO("Visualizing plan 1 (pose goal) %s", success ? "" : "FAILED");
sleep(5.0);
if (success) {
    move_group_->move(); //execute(move_plan);
} else {
    ROS_ERROR(
            "Error while planning position of arm, no move command was sent!\n");
    return false;
}
sleep(2.0);
```

There are to outcomes of this code. The most crucial is when `moveit` exits with error:

```
[ INFO] [1444747356.697432845]: Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.
[ WARN] [1444747356.697539343]: Execution of motions should always start at the robot''s current state. Ignoring the state supplied as start state in the motion planning request
[ INFO] [1444747356.697561413]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[ INFO] [1444747356.697634046]: Starting state is just outside bounds (joint 'elbow_pitch_joint'). Assuming within bounds.
[ INFO] [1444747356.704333992]: Loading robot model 'cyton_gamma_1500'...
[ INFO] [1444747356.704373020]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1444747356.774530395]: No planner specified. Using default.
[ INFO] [1444747356.774593336]: LBKPIECE1: Attempting to use default projection.
[ INFO] [1444747356.774859013]: Allocating specialized state sampler for state space
[ INFO] [1444747356.774898663]: LBKPIECE1: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure
***** Internal Program Error - assertion (satisfiesBounds(state1) && satisfiesBounds(state2)) failed in virtual double ompl::base::SO3StateSpace::distance(const ompl::base::State*, const ompl::base::State*) const:
/tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-ompl-1.0.0003094-0trusty-20141029-0351/src/ompl/base/spaces/src/SO3StateSpace.cpp(284): The states passed to SO3StateSpace::distance are not within bounds. Call SO3StateSpace::enforceBounds() in, e.g., ompl::control::ODESolver::PostPropagationEvent, ompl::control::StatePropagator, or ompl::base::StateValidityChecker
[move_group-7] process has died [pid 1099, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group __name:=move_group __log:=/home/elod/.ros/log/61d301e0-71b8-11e5-b90c-2c44fd0c995f/move_group-7.log].
log file: /home/elod/.ros/log/61d301e0-71b8-11e5-b90c-2c44fd0c995f/move_group-7*.log
```

Or `moveit` throws an unmet constrain error where the  `eef` string is the `camera_front`:

```
[ INFO] [1444746408.872008469]: Planning adapters have added states at index positions: [ 0 ]
[ERROR] [1444746408.873127307]: Computed path is not valid. Invalid states at index locations: [ 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ] out of 11. Explanations follow in command line. Contacts are published on /move_group/display_contacts
[ INFO] [1444746408.873301981]: Orientation constraint violated for link 'camera_front'. Quaternion desired: 0.574730 -0.533082 0.492382 -0.378245, quaternion actual: -0.118576 0.830576 -0.542143 -0.046519, error: x=1.156043, y=0.977443, z=1.148112, tolerance: x=0.150000, y=0.150000, z=0.150000
```

**UPDATE 1**

In case, I have only position constrain (orientation constrain not added to the list), than the planning is successfully done most of the time.

**UPDATE 2**

I tired with another planner to `RRTConnectkConfigDefault` and I did not experience the same problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219054/planning-error-with-path-constrains/) by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2015-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fond a workaround. On the official sites is written that the `LBKPIECE1` is experimental and if no planner ID is set, than this is the default. So, I changed the planner to `RRT` which works well without crashing `moveit`.

```
move_group_->setPlannerId("RRTConnectkConfigDefault");
```

---

Originally posted by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) with karma: 231 on 2015-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0